# Are netbook cooling pads really worth it?

Tags: netbook, cooling-pad

I'm tempted to work with a cooling pad at home, since my netbook is my primary computer, and if you are following my questions I plan to buy a dual core netbook that I'll use as desktop most of the time.

I want to assemble a little workstation and I want to hook up everything, monitor, keyboard, mouse and cooling fan (if I buy the cooling pad) to the netbook using a usb hub.

I even want to place the netbook vertically so the air can flow freely.

What are the adventages and disadventages of cooling pads with and without fan?

Or a negative and positive past experience from you works for me.

Comment: I feel like this question is very localized and depends on how you use your netbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their effectiveness varies greatly depending on the pad and the laptop in question.  It all depends on how hot the laptop gets under the various loads, the configuration of the laptop, the laptop's cooling system, and the design of the pad.  Will you get some benefit?  Sure, but it can range from limited benefit to moderate.

Short answer:  It can't hurt, and it may help a little.  But it's not going to be a lot.  You will probably get better results from opening up your laptop case from time to time and blowing out any dust and debris that collects.

Comment: I think I made my mind about the cooling pads. One point for both of you! Blake gets selected because it directly addresses my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Cooling pads are most useful when you're actually using a laptop on your lap (or other soft surface that might cover/block the vents on bottom).  There's not much point for in a fixed desk.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question, but it certainly good to know.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, a netbook does not get hot enough to warrant the use of a cooling pad.  I have only once recommended a laptop cooling pad to a client.  He was using a 17" high-end laptop (600W power supply) for CAD use with two additional monitors.

High performance, desktop replacement style laptops run hot enough that coolers can be beneficial.  For the most part, netbooks do not.

Comment: Wouldn't it help in the long term? Suppose I use my netbook computer as primary at least 8 hours a day (this is not my case, yet, I'm employed for god sake) How would a cooling pad affect in the long run? I forgot to mention that my house doesn't have air conditioning.